# Use apply on a multi-dimension array

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, apply, sapply

A normal matrix would be 2-dimension matrix. But, I can initialise:

```
a<-array(0,dim=c(2,3,4,5))
```

Which is a 2*4*5*3 matrix, or array.

Command

```
apply(a,c(2,3),sum)
```

will give a 4*5 array, contain the sum over elements in the 1st and 4th dimension.

Why it that? As far as I know, in the `apply` function, 1 indicates rows, 2 indicates columns, but what does 3 mean here?

We need some abstraction here.

Comment: 1:n are dimensions apply works on, starting with rows.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to understand `apply` on an array is to try some examples. Here's some data modified from the last example object [in the documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html):

```
> z <- array(1:24, dim = 2:4)
> dim(z)
[1] 2 3 4

> apply(z, 1, function(x) sum(x))
[1] 144 156
> apply(z, 2, function(x) sum(x))
[1]  84 100 116
> apply(z, 3, function(x) sum(x))
[1]  21  57  93 129
```

What's going on here? Well, we create a three-dimensional array `z`. If you use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` you get row sums (two values because there are two rows), if you use `MARGIN=2` you get column sums (three values because there are three columns), and if you use `MARGIN=3` you get sums across the array's third dimension (four values because there are four levels to the third dimension of the array).

If you specify a vector for `MARGIN`, like `c(2,3)` you get the sum of the rows for each column and level of the third dimension. Note how in the above examples, the results from `apply` with `MARGIN=1` are the row sums and with `MARGIN=2` the column sums, respectively, of the matrix seen in the result below:

```
> apply(z, c(2,3), function(x) sum(x))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3   15   27   39
[2,]    7   19   31   43
[3,]   11   23   35   47
```

If you specify all of the dimensions as `MARGIN=c(1,2,3)` you simply get the original three-dimensional object:

```
> all.equal(z, apply(z, c(1,2,3), function(x) sum(x)))
[1] TRUE
```

Best way to learn here is just to start playing around with some real matrices. Your example data aren't helpful for looking at sums because all of the array entries are zero.

Comment: I did not get what you mean by "If you specify a vector for MARGIN, like c(2,3) you get the sum of the rows for each column and level of the third dimension. "

Comment: @GeekCat As opposed to calculating the marginal sum across rows or across columns, it is calculating the marginal sum of the array across both those dimensions (well, with `c(2,3)` it's actually columns and the array's third dimension but hopefully you see the point). It's hard to put into words, I think, so looking at some examples is really helpful.