# Make a function on a 3D matrix to produce means and histograms

Tags: r

I have data like that :

```
N = 100
matr <- matrix(rnorm(3*6*N), N)
matr_T <- array(as.vector(t(matr)), dim=c(6, 3, N))
```

It's the result of a simulation. My columns represent my territories, the rows a unit of time, and the 3d the set of simulations of the estimated parameters for each column / row.

I would like to do several things with this dataset. I would like to do a function that would allow me to make a histogram on 3d data for each column/row (here 18 histograms) in a multipanel figure. But I would also like to produce an array (2d) with `mean()` and an other array (2d) with `sd()` as for previous histograms (array of 3*6). Can be an `apply()` in which I could choose the function (`hist()`, `mean()`, `sd()`, etc.) Can you help me please?

Thank you !

Comment: So, just that I can follow, you want to have 18 histogramms and two 6*3 matrices, one with means and one with sds?

Comment: Yep, I would like to have a figure with as much histogram above as the column*row (histogram on the data of the third dimension which are simulation of parameters), and also to have two 2D tables of the means and sd data of the third dimension. 
I thought maybe to a function in which one could choose hist or mean or sd. But maybe there are easier solutions! Thank you !

Comment: Ok, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23303145/9524065) could maybe help you for the mean/sd-part.
I'll try to figure the histogram-thing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT no. 2

Now it's using the far superior `lapply` for the plots and plotting in a sensible structure.

```r
N = 100
matr <- matrix(rnorm(3*6*N), N)
matr_T <- array(as.vector(t(matr)), dim=c(6, 3, N))
apply(matr_T,1:2,mean)


apply(matr_T,1:2,sd)



library(ggplot2) # for histograms


library(cowplot) # for grid arrangement


# create list to access Dimensions in lapply
dims <- list(row = rep(1:nrow(matr_T),each = ncol(matr_T)),
             col = rep(1:ncol(matr_T),times = nrow(matr_T)))

plots <- lapply(seq_along(dims$row),
function(i){ 
  ggplot(data.frame(x = matr_T[dims$row[i],dims$col[i],]),aes(x = x)) + 
    geom_histogram(bins = 10, col = 'black', fill = 'white') +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(title = paste('row:',dims$row[i],'\n','col:',dims$col[i]))
})

plot_grid(plotlist = plots, ncol = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thx it's work like that !
Would it be possible to automatically add names to figures of the type: [1,1], [1,2], [1,3], or something like that to differentiate them? Thank you !

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, your function has transposed the order of the histograms?

Comment: No, I had to transpose the result-matrices since the plot_grid plotted them in a strange order. But I'll change it so you can have your positions as names.