# Mid value in a 3d array

Tags: r, arrays, matrix

So I have an array: `erf[longitude, latitude, time]` which I calculated from: `erf = r1 - (r2 + r3)` where `r1,r2,r3` also `[longitude, latitude, time]` arrays. So my question is how do I create a mid value for `erf` for all the values of time and end up with a 2d array `erf [longitude, latitude]` ?

Comment: Could you create a small example array with numbers (say dimensions c(2,2,3)) and show what your expected outcome is please e.g. what is the *mid value*

Comment: you can `apply(erf, c(1, 2), mean)` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23303145/20513099